# How to install .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

I downloaded and install .NET 4.5 beta on windows 7, but not sure where it is installed.

1. Check C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework, can't find out folder for 4.5
2. Open VS 2010 and open property for one of project in a solution, there is no 4.5 in the list for Target Framework, only .Net Framework 4 there.

How to make sure the installation okay and how to use it?

Comment: Have you installed VS11?

Comment: Does it matter where it is installed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

.NET 4.5 is an [in place](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx) [replacement](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40) for .NET 4.0 - that means that the assemblies are in the v4.0.xxx folder.

You can also find the assemblies in a reference assemblies folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework.
```